# Отображение картинок на странице JSP, загруженных с JS кода

Tags: javascript, css, spring, jsp

Есть следующий фрагмент кода метода на JS:

```
// в зависимости от уровня рейтинга исполнителя рисуем разными цветами его ник и фон
if(parseFloat(executor_rate) >= 4.0) {
    executor_info.style.color = "green";
    executor_info.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/flag_reiting_green.png)";
}
else if(parseFloat(executor_rate) >= 3.0) {
    executor_info.style.color = "orange";
    executor_info.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/flag_reiting_yellow.png)";
}
else {
    executor_info.style.color = "red";
    executor_info.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/flag_reiting.png)";
}
```

Проблема в том, что картинки, которые подгружаются с метода, в странице JSP не отображаются. При этом, такие же пути в css файле работают корректно. 
Помогите пожалуйста или направьте на необходимую литературу.
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Используйте абсолютные пути.

Comment: Попробовал вот так: "url(d:/Prog/site/src/main/webapp/static/css/images/flag_reiting.png)". К сожалению ничего не изменилось(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Встречая в html-странице или css-файле относительный url-путь, браузер подставляет его к абсолютному пути документа, в котором его встретил, формируя тем самым полный url. После чего делается запрос к web-серверу по полученному URL. Если ваш css-файл лежит в `/static/css` и в нём указан путь `images/flag_reiting.png`, то браузер запросит `http://server.domain/static/css/images/flag_reiting.png`. А если вы попытаетесь этот же путь использовать в скрипте, который лежит, предположим, в `/static/js`, то браузер запросит уже `http://server.domain/static/js/images/flag_reiting.png`. Естественно, web-сервер по этому url необходимый файл не найдёт.

Используйте абсолютные пути:

```
executor_info.style.backgroundImage = "url(/static/css/images/flag_reiting.png)";
```

Comment: Такой вариант тоже пробовал. Не меняется ничего(

Comment: Что в логах web-сервера? Запросы появляются? Код ответа какой?

Comment: Та логи, к сожалению пока не настраивал. Страница грузится как положено. Картинки с html (<img src="<c:url value='/static/css/images/logo.png'/>" alt="logo" id="logopom" />) и css (background-image: url(images/logo.png);) файлов нормально подгружаются. Все скрипты работают. Вообщем все норм. А вот конкретно картинки с кода JS не грузятся. Папка с JS лежит на одном уровне с CSS - /static/js/...

Comment: Тогда открывайте DevTools браузера и смотрите, что он запрашивает и, что ему отвечает web-сервер.

Comment: Логично, у вашего приложения есть контекст - `test`. А значит и абсолютный url должен его содержать - `/test/static/css/images/flag_reiting.png`.

Comment: хм, не совсем понимаю что нашаманил, но заработало с изначально указанным Вами путем). "url(/static/css/images/flag_reiting.png)". Спасибо огромное!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)